# How to change default Nginx setting on Homestead Laravel Virtualbox VM

Tags: laravel, nginx, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I merely followed the default [Laravel Homestead setup](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/homestead) here using VirtualBox. Working great.

But I need an additional Nginx rewrite setting in my apps vhost file on the VM, something like;

```
location / {
   if ($request_method !~ "(POST)"){
   rewrite ....
   }

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

I can add that manually to the vhost file on the VM, but it's removed every time I provision my box.

How do I make that setting automatically applied when provision my vagrant VM box.

Is there a `after provision hook`, so I can run a script, or is there another easy solution available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way to achieve this is editing  [`scripts/serve.sh`](https://github.com/laravel/homestead/blob/master/scripts/serve.sh) file, which contains server block template in `block` variable.

Comment: Problem with this solution is that as soon as you update Homestead, your edits are lost. I'm also looking for a solution and want something that doesn't alter source files.